# ESPN mobile site, jquery?

Tags: jquery, mobile, espn

Does anyone know what ESPN mobile is using for their interaction, jquery?

It looks like they are using CSS3 for browsers that support it, as it downgrades for unsupported browsers to basic colors and non-rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

On their "normal" website they do use jQuery. But not on the "mobile" site. It is mostly Flash. Just look at the page-source when you are on the page.

Comment: What are you talking about? Their mobile site is not Flash - how would it run in the iPhone if it were in flash?

Comment: I didn't realise that when you visit the ESPN mobile website from a PC it redirects you to http://proxy.espn.go.com/mobile/products/index which seems to use Flash heavily. iPhone does not support Flash, but that is Apple's policy, there are other smart phones that do. See Adobe's website e.g. As the first runtime release of the Open Screen Project and a core component of the Adobe Flash Platform, Adobe Flash Player 10.1 allows you to make your web content contextually relevant and reach more users across a wide spectrum of Internet-connected devices, including smartphones, netbooks, and PCs.

Comment: 4 things - 1) when I go to ESPN's mobile website (m.espn.com) on a PC, it takes me to m.espn.go.com/wireless, not the page that you linked to. 2) What in the world does your insane Flash fanboy rambling have to do with the question at hand? ALL mobile browsers go to the flash-free mobile site. 3) That page you linked to is not "mostly Flash". The only Flash on that page is the banner at the top, below the navigation. 4) The iPhone isn't the only mobile OS that doesn't support flash - Windows Phone 7 and BlackBerry don't either. Only Android does right now.

Comment: Charles, It was a genuine mistake on my part. I'm not a "fan" of Flash - quite the opposite. The browser on my PC DOES take me to the site I mentioned earlier when I try to go to ESPN's mobile site: espn.go.com/mobileespn/index. Looking at the source for that webpage "flash" is mentioned over 20 times! Instead of being negative and complaining that I don't know what I'm talking about, why not be constructive and answer Xtian's question? PS I didn't say that iPhone is the only mobile not to support Flash. Your initial comment implied that NONE did.

Comment: In no way did my initial comment imply that no mobile platforms supported flash - all that can be implied from my statement is that the site DOES run on the iPhone (which doesn't run flash). And that page you say is their mobile site (espn.go.com/mobileespn/index)? That IS NOT their mobile site. The URL I mentioned (m.espn.com) is their mobile site. Why do you think the URL you mentioned is their mobile site? Go to espn.com in a mobile browser and you will be redirected to m.espn.com, not espn.go.com/mobileespn/index.

Comment: Oh, and searching for the word "flash" in source doesn't mean anything whatsoever. You clearly DON'T know what programming for Flash on a web page entails. According to your logic, this URL is loaded with Flash because the word "flash" is in the HTML source for this page over 15 times as well. There are two .swf files referenced on that page - which if you actually understood what you were talking about, you would know are Flash files. So two flash files on an entire page is "mostly Flash"? Sorry - nope.

Comment: Charles, as I said I made a genuine mistake with the web address. I googled ESPN mobile website and "espn.go.com/mobileespn/index" was the first entry. YES you are right, I don't know what programming for flash entails - I've only used it once or twice. I can't help Xtian, and neither by the sound of it can you, so let's agree to differ and leave it at that now and be more constructive.

Answer (score 0):

The markup for the ESPN Mobile site depends on the device.  When browsing using an IPhone, I see two small JavaScript references related to pop-ups.  No JQuery.

http://static.mobile.espn.go.com/wireless/js/main.r3.js

http://static.mobile.espn.go.com/wireless/js/popup.class.js

Other devices may get a different result, for example, the Blackberry site is simpler and has no JavaScript.